# Mongo.Cursor#map(callback, [thisArg]) with ECMAScript 6 arrow functions

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, ecmascript-6

I am using Meteor/Mongo and looking at the [documentation][1], I am still not sure how to use the `Cursor#map` with *ECMAScript 6* arrow functions.

I have a `cursor`:

```
private messages: Mongo.Cursor<Message>;
```

of `Messages`:

```
  interface Message {
    _id?: string;
    chatId?: string;
    senderId?: string;
    ownership?: string;
    content?: string;
    createdAt?: Date;
    changeDate?: boolean;
    readByReceiver?: boolean;
  }
```

and I would like to return a list of `messages` that match a specific `_id`.

When I try:

```
let _id: string = newMessage._id;
const matchedMessageIds: string[] = this.messages.map(({_id}) => _id)
    .reduce((result, _id) => result.concat(_id), []);
```

which kind of works, but it returns the results for the whole `cursor`, and not just the one matching the `_id`.

Comment: What do you mean by "matching `_id`"? Did you mean to `filter` not `map`?

Comment: yes, maybe filter is the right option, I am new to Meteor and Mongo sorry.

Comment: So, what do you *want* to do?

Comment: I can't see a `filter` function on a `Cursor`:  http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#mongo_cursor

Comment: Can't you use the Mongo selector to filter your results before fetching?

Comment: I'm not sure?  What function on the Cursor should I sue for that?

Comment: Assuming `_id` is the primary key for the collection there will only be one matching document and you can find that directly using `.findOne(_id)`

Answer (score 0):

Use a `filer`:

```
const filter_id: string = newMessage._id;
const matchedMessageIds: string[] = this.messages.map(({_id}) => _id)
  .filter(_id: string => _id === filter_id);
```